# How can i writte a regex to validate only number greater than 0 and 0?

Tags: javascript, regex

currently with this regex i am validating the numer greater than 1,

```
 /^\d*[1-9]\d*$/
```

but right now i need a regex to validate numbers greater or equal to zero

or i mean it does not have to allow the simbol '-' minus

Comment: `^\d+$` should be sufficient.

Comment: @Unmitigated Depends on whether leading zeroes should be allowed, for example is `007` a valid number? The fix for this should be easy however, e.g. `^(0)|([1-9]\d*)$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
/^\d+$/
```

But i suggest to convert it to number and check. It's more efficient. Assuming you have a variable contains digits named `number`

```
let isPositive = +number >= 0;
console.log(isPositive)
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it!  Just add a zero in the square brackets

```
 /^\d*[0-9]\d*$/
```

Comment: This matches on leading zeroes, e.g. `007`. I'm not sure whether that is intended by the author.